# Two asynchronous method calls in watch() in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to find the postal code of an address; for this, I am using a geocode service. It needs two service calls to fetch the geocode.

```
 scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (angular.isObject(newVal)) {
                var userEnteredStreetNum = '';

                if (angular.isString(oldVal)) {
                    var userEnteredStreetNumMatch = STREET_NUM_REGEX.exec($.trim(oldVal));

                    if (userEnteredStreetNumMatch !== null) {
                        userEnteredStreetNum = userEnteredStreetNumMatch[1];
                    }
                }
                    var addrInfo = _.map(['street_number', 'route', 'postal_code'], function (addrType) {
                        var obj = _.findWhere(newVal.address_components, { types: [addrType] });
                        return obj && obj.short_name;
                    });

                if (angular.isUndefined(addrInfo[2])) {
                    var results = newVal.address_components;
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                    scope.$watch()
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': newVal.formatted_address }, function (results, status) {

                        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var result = results[0].address_components;
                            geocoder.geocode({ 'location': results[0].geometry.location }, function (results, status) {
                                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    var result = results[0].address_components,
                                     postalInfo = _.map(['postal_code', 'street_number'], function (addrType) {
                                         var obj = _.findWhere(result, { types: [addrType] });
                                         return obj && obj.short_name;
                                     });

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }



            }
        });
```

The above code written in `watch()`. The problem is it won't reflect meanse the postal code does not appear in next textbox until the user mouses out from textbox. But it should reflect without the need of mouseout or tab.

The watch function gets executed and then the async call is completed. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: I took a stab at editing this, but there are a few things to clarify:  first, what do you mean by "reflect"?  Second, the full context of the code may be better to provide (including the `$scope.$watch()` bit).

Comment: Based on what condition the watch() function is getting called. Share more code.

Comment: I have given full code now.